# AngularJs json-formatter json attribute as scope variable

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to present json in one of the view using [json-formatter](https://github.com/mohsen1/json-formatter).

In controller I am using service that is requesting schema via rest API. When request is completed result is assigned to the scope variable. Code snippet below:

```
.controller('SchemaCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Schema','$log',    function($scope, $routeParams, Schema,$log){
    Schema.show($routeParams.name).then(function(schema){
        $scope.schema = schema;
        $scope.schemaShow = true;
    });
```

In the view I have next code:

```
{{schema}}
<div>
    <json-formatter open="1" json="{{schema}}"></json-formatter>
</div>
```

Unfortunatelly after running example I am receiving next error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{schema}}] starting at [{schema}}].
{{schema}}
```

I know that the problem is caused by json-formatter. Directive is interpreted before angular replace `{{schema}}` with proper value. How can I use [json-formatter](https://github.com/mohsen1/json-formatter) in order to pass values via scope variables?

Btw.
When I use hardcoded json value everything is working well.

Comment: is schema a JSON object? or an interpreted JS object? i.e. is it a string or a js object? Have you `console.log`'ed the `schema`

Comment: schema is a JSON object but even if I am assigning JSON.stringify(schema) result is the same. In the console.log results seems to be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json` is 2-way binding in `json-formatter`, so no need interpolation mark `{{}}` here

```
<div>
    <json-formatter open="1" json="schema"></json-formatter>
</div>
```